# Can't install mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm

```
pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) .. done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) .. error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppD
ata\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mmb7531p\\mysqlclient_a141c7c0a933439fbe19807e877c7cc2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install
-mmb7531p\\mysqlclient_a141c7c0a933439fbe19807e877c7cc2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.St
ringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'
))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-44gqcvbi'
       cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mmb7531p\mysqlclient_a141c7c0a933439fbe19807e877c7cc2\
  Complete output (25 lines):
  c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mmb7531p\\mysqlclient_a141c7c0a933439fbe19807e877c7cc2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-insta
ll-mmb7531p\\mysqlclient_a141c7c0a933439fbe19807e877c7cc2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.
StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'
"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ylfwp41x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\
users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Include\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mmb7531p\mysqlclient_a141c7c0a933439fbe19807e877c7cc2\
    Complete output (25 lines):
    c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'        
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools        
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys
.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mmb7531p\\mysqlclient_a141c7c0a933439fbe19807e877c7cc2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-mmb7531p\\mysqlclient_a141c7c0a933439fbe19807e877c7cc2\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if 
os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(com
pile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ylfwp41x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed
 --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'am trying to install mysqlclient in Pycharm. But i couldn't,its showing me these errors.There are errors while buliding wheel for mysqlclient. Django version is 3.2.18. Pip version is 21.3.1. Does this error happens due to mismatch of versions of pip and mysqlclient? ............................................................................................................

Comment: The error shows that you need C++ 14.0 build tools. Did you try it with that?

Answer (score 0):

why don't use the MSI setup file to install it. it's okay with `pip`, I will check what is the problem, but for the time being go here & install: [**https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/**](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)

MySQL client installs the full suite in your machine (including the CLI). You said about PyCharm, it is going to use the CLI. So just install the full suite setup.

See, I just did this,

```
PS C:\Users\Archisman> pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading mysqlclient-2.1.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (178 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 178.4/178.4 kB 10.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-2.1.1

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\Archisman\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
PS C:\Users\Archisman>
```

**I had installed MySQL through the setup file & works everywhere. So, just download the setup & install it. `pip install mysqlclient` may leave some of the packages to be installed & that's causing the error.**

Also don't forget that **MySQL needs MS Visual Studio Build Tools**. So, it's better run the setup.

**UPDATE**
Found this in your Shell:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

Just what I guessed.

Comment: The SO needs to know how to fix the issue with his current install method. Suggesting an alternate method is not invalid but voids the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As the error messages indicate, The problem could be the "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools". So try installing that depandency.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my python version 3.8, the problem solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).